# Getting the except django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured while querying DB

Tags: django, exception, django-models, django-views

I am trying to fetch a few rows from the DB using the following code in my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from fusioncharts.models import QRC_DB

def display_data(request,component):
    query_results = QRC_DB.objects.get(component_name__contains=component)
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at the component %s." % component)
```

For the above, I am getting the following exception:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'Piechart_Excel.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

However whenever I am **removing/commenting out** the below line, the above exception disappears:

```
query_results = QRC_DB.objects.get(component_name__contains=component)
```

The 2 urls files are as follows:

urls.py under the app directory

```
from django.urls import path
from fusioncharts import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('push-data/', views.push_data, name='push-data'),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('display_data/<str:component>', views.display_data, name='display_data'),
]
```

and urls.py under the main project directory

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('fusioncharts.urls'))
]
```

Edit: 
Settings.py file is as follows:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'fusioncharts',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Piechart_Excel.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'fusioncharts', 'templates', 'fusioncharts'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Piechart_Excel.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {  
    'default': {  
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  
        'NAME': 'QRC_Report_First_Project',
        'USER':'xxxx',  
        'PASSWORD':'xxxx',  
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'3306'  
    }  
} 



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Can anyone say what's going wrong? How come just one line of code which queries the DB is causing the above exception?

Comment: where do you have Piechart_Excel.urls, error does not point to code you posted

Comment: That's present in the Settings.py file as follows: 

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Piechart_Excel.urls'

Comment: Don't worry, those are not at all a concern here....Those are dummy.

Comment: `If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import`. Are you sure you don't have circular imports?

Comment: Well, nowhere I could detect that. BTW if I just remove the following line: 

query_results = QRC_DB.objects.get(component_name__contains=component)

then the exception vanishes. So what could be the cause of that exception ?